# Push notifications in ionic3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have been trying to implement registering and receiving push notifications in 
my ionic3 app fro the past 2 days but nothing seems working because of the version that I am using right now.

First of all my versions;

rxjs : 5.5.11

Angular : 5.2.11

typescript : ~2.6.2

firebase : 5.8.2

@angular/fire: ^5.1.1

angularfire2 : ^5.1.1

Things that I have tried so far:

1)AngularFirestore-Firebase Native

I am getting Object(...) is not function error with this and I realized this because of my rxjs version. AngularFireStore is using rxjs 6 or above. I updated rxjs to 6 but this time typescrit gave error. Because rxjs was using ts 2.8 features. I wanted update ts but ionic was not supporting it. I don't want to migrate to ionic4 becaasu I don't want to spend time for this.

2)ionic-push

I am getting the same Object(...) is not a function error again.

3) FCM

Strange enough, I can not put FCM to the providers in the app.module.ts. Ts giving error that FCM is not suitable to be a provider.

So I need a way to implement push notifications with the package versions that I am using right now? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently run into the same issue when trying to run AngularFire + Firebase in Ionic 3.  In my case I didn't need AngularFire (often to store something in Firebase DB).  So I just used `cordova-plugin-firebase@2.0.5` with `@ionic-native/firebase@^4.20.0`.  I'm able to build and get notifications working with Android (haven't tried iOS yet).

So if you just need the push notification parts, try just grabbing the Firebase plugin (and Ionic Native wrapper).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try with these versions. Can you share simple code for registering and receiving notifs with those versions? or are they the same with above versions?

Comment: Should be largely the same.  I used these docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/firebase/ and https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase

Comment: Man It could not appreciate you more. Finally It worked even with AngualarfireDatabase. Thank you so much.

Comment: Cool - glad it helped!  Please mark this as answered if this is, indeed the answer.